# How to return from a function with promise(Guzzle)

Tags: php, guzzle

```
function myfunc($finalArray){

        $url = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $countOfSuccess = 0;

        $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', $url);

        $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) use ($finalArray,$countOfSuccess) {
            $countOfSuccess ++ ;
            echo $countOfSuccess;
            echo count($finalArray);
            if(myresponse is valid){
                return "Successfully"; // Want to return from there
            }

        });
        $promise->wait();

}
```

Below is the if condition return. The call is coming inside the if

```
if(myresponse is valid){
    return "Successfully"; // Want to return from there
}
```

So this return is not working and the calling function doesn't get the return value

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation (https://github.com/guzzle/promises#synchronous-wait), you should be able to do something like this:

```
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request);
$promise->then(function ($response) use ($finalArray,$countOfSuccess, &$promise) {
    $countOfSuccess ++ ;
    echo $countOfSuccess;
    echo count($finalArray);
    if(myresponse is valid){
        $promise->resolve('Success');
    }

});
echo $promise->wait(); // should return 'Success'
```

Comment: Can u tell me how to get response of multiple async task at once or is there any way possible to check whether all async task are completed or not in guzzle.

Answer (score 0):

> Can u tell me how to get response of multiple async task at once or is there any way possible to check whether all async task are completed or not in guzzle.

You probably need [`all()` function from Guzzle's promises library](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/master/src/functions.php#L220).

There are more functions to combine and introspect promises, take a look at the source code.